# testing a polling service

Tags: angular, unit-testing, rxjs

I have an angular service whose job is to poll the API ever 60 seconds to verify whether or not the client is still connected:

```
export class AppService {

  get isOnline$(): Observable<{ online: boolean }> {
    return this.isOnlineSource.asObservable();
  }
  private isOnlineSource = new BehaviorSubject<{ online: boolean }>({ online: true });

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    timer(0, 60000).switchMap(() =>
      this.http.get(`${environment.apiUrl}/api/assessments/amionline`, environment.httpOptions)
        .map(x => {
          return { online: true };
        })
        .catch((err, caught) => {
          return of({ online: false });
        })
    ).
      subscribe(data => this.isOnlineSource.next(data));
  }

}
```

How do I go about testing this code? I thought a fakeAsync block with a tick() would be enough to trigger the observable, but httpMock is receiving no requests

Test code:

```
 it('should return online equals false.', fakeAsync(() => {
   appService.isOnline$.subscribe(data => {
    expect(data.online).toEqual(false);
   });
   tick(70000);
   httpMock.expectOne(url).flush(undefined, mockErrorResponse);
   httpMock.verify();
  }));
 });
```

Note: the test is using HttpClientTestingModule and httpMock is HttpTestingController

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/cartant/rxjs-marbles/blob/master/README.md#fakeschedulers

Comment: What does that do that calling fakeAsync() and tick() doesn't?

Comment: It patches the schedulers so that RxJS uses the same fake time concept as zone.js. Basically, it just makes RxJS play nice with `fakeAsync` - which it calls internally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem that's preventing your test from working has been addressed in [this PR](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/pull/3851) - which has recently been merged.

Angular's `fakeAsync` patches time-related functions - like `setTimeout` - and it also patches the `Date` class - in particular, it patches `Date.now`. Unfortunately, prior to the PR being merged, RxJS took a reference to `Date.now` before it could be patched by `fakeAsync`.

That means that your test will work when the next release of RxJS is published.

Until then, you could either use the [`fakeSchedulers`](https://github.com/cartant/rxjs-marbles#fakeschedulers) function in my `rxjs-marbles` package or could use a similar technique to patch the scheduler's `now` method. (The [Angular-specific implementation of `fakeSchedulers`](https://github.com/cartant/rxjs-marbles/blob/master/source/jasmine/angular.ts) is simple.)

If you are using RxJS version 5, there is an alternative: you can import [`zone-patch-rxjs-fake-async.js`](https://github.com/angular/zone.js/blob/master/dist/zone-patch-rxjs-fake-async.js) and have zone.js patch the schedulers. Just add `import 'zone.js/dist/zone-patch-rxjs-fake-async'` to your `src/test.ts` file.

Comment: Thanks for the added explanation. Unfortunately, now I get "TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object", and I can't figure out where it's coming from.

Comment: What versions of Angular and RxJS are you using?

Comment: Angular 5.2.11 and RxJS 5.5.11

Comment: `fakeSchedulers` exists only in the version of `rxjs-marbles` that supports RxJS version 6. However, there is an alternative: patch the schedulers with zone.js. I've updated the answer.